# I am trying to call using Twilio sdk but my call is disconnected in 2 or 3 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio

I am trying to call using **[Twilio sdk](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client)** but my call is disconnected in 2 or 3 seconds. My Twilio account is upgrated. I am using below code

```
-(IBAction)mainButtonPressed:(id)sender
    {
        BasicPhoneAppDelegate* delegate = (BasicPhoneAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        BasicPhone* basicPhone = delegate.phone;

        if (!basicPhone.connection || basicPhone.connection.state == TCConnectionStateDisconnected)
        {
            NSString* strToNumber = self.textOutgoingDest.text;
            if (strToNumber && ![strToNumber isEqualToString:@""]) {

                switch (_eOutgoingType) {
                    case BPOutgoingNumber:
                        break;

                    case BPOutgoingClient:
                        strToNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client:%@", strToNumber];
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                NSDictionary* dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strToNumber, @"To", nil];
                [self.phone connectWithParams:dictParams];
            }
            else {
                [self.phone connectWithParams:nil];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [basicPhone disconnect];
        }

        [self syncMainButton];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue

```
-(IBAction)mainButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    BasicPhoneAppDelegate* delegate = (BasicPhoneAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    BasicPhone* basicPhone = delegate.phone;

    if (!basicPhone.connection || basicPhone.connection.state == TCConnectionStateDisconnected)
    {
        NSString* strToNumber = self.textOutgoingDest.text;
        if (strToNumber && ![strToNumber isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            strToNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strToNumber];
            NSDictionary* dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strToNumber, @"number", nil];
            [self.phone connectWithParams:dictParams];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.phone connectWithParams:nil];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [basicPhone disconnect];
    }

    [self syncMainButton];
}
```